# Android JUnit xml report not created on device

Tags: android, ant, junit

Do I need to do anything special to have a JUnit xml report created when I run robotium tests against my Android application?

I have my application, and a few Robotium tests that I am running. I run my tests from the command line with:

```
 ant emma debug install test fetch-test-report
```

and I have manually added the "fetch-test-report" task for ant, as explained by other on the site:

```
<target name="fetch-test-report" >
<xpath
    expression="/manifest/@package"
    input="${tested.project.dir}/AndroidManifest.xml"
    output="tested.package" />
<echo>Downloading XML test report...</echo>
<exec
    executable="${adb}"
    failonerror="true" >
    <arg line="${adb.device.arg}" />
    <arg value="pull" />
    <arg value="/data/data/${tested.package}/files/junit-report.xml" />
    <arg value="report/junit-report.xml" />
</exec>
```

When I run the tests, everything goes through just fine, but the last task complains that the report file isn't found:

```
remote object '/data/data/com.packagename/files/junit-report.xml' does not exist
```

Do I need to do something special to get the JUnit report created?
I am using an HTC One V for testing, but I have also tried with simulators and I still get the same result - no files are being saved.

Is there maybe any way to specify the location where the JUnit file would be created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not able to go through with this without using some custom library. With either JUnit 3 or JUnit 4, the junit report is not created on the device.

I had to start using this library to generate the junit report:
http://zutubi.com/source/projects/android-junit-report/

Now the report is correctly created and I have no problem retrieving it from the device.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should check TEST-all.xml instead of junit-report.xml
Btw you can always check it with adb, if file really exist

Comment: Actually, it seems nothing is being saved. I can try "adb pull /data/data/packagename" and I get the following: "pull: building file list...
0 files pulled. 0 files skipped."